# How to create a Gmail group from recipient list?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I have an email with tens of recipients. I would like to create a contact group from it without adding each of them one at a time. How can I do that in Gmail?

The internet is full of old instructions where you paste the list when you click "add contact" in the group, but that does not seem to be possible in the current Gmail interface.

Answer (score 1):

> ...that does not seem to be possible in the current Gmail interface.

Correct. So what you have to do is:

### Revert to the "Old Contacts" by leaving the "Contacts Preview" screen.

After that you just follow the steps you already know and are familiar with.
I will go through them though, just in case.

---

1. Go to your email and copy the recipient list by clicking on the little arrow next to the "*to me*" button found under the sender's name.
2. Go to your Contacts. It defaults to the new "Contacts Preview Screen".
3. Look at the left side, find and click the "*More*" link.

[image: contacts-01.png]

4. **Click on "*Leave the Contacts preview*"**.

[image: contacts-02.png]

5. The page will reload and you will be taken to the familiar "old" screen.
   Click on the group you want to bulk add your new contacts.

[image: contacts-03.png]

6. Find the "*Add to group*" middle button on the top.

[image: contacts-04.png]

7. Paste your recipient list in the box and click Add.

[image: contacts-05.png]

8. Done.

[image: contacts-06.png]